# Images loop until async succeeds after adding ViewHolder

Tags: java, android, performance

I'm having some problems with my async task and ViewHolder...

Before even using ViewHolder everything worked nice but I wanted to optimize and reuse childViews for better performance. However, since I added ViewHolder the images start to loop through until it imageload is done and then it shows correct image.

My problem is I don't want this random loop until load, why is it happening? 
I've been trying to set visibity to GONE before it go into async task and even set the ImageView.setBitmap to null...still it does this loop of images until loading the correct one..

It looks like a cool feature but I dont want it right now :)

My code looks like this:

**Adapter**

```
public class ContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contacts> {

private final Context _context;
private final ArrayList<Contact> _contactList;
ViewHolder holder;
ImageHelper task;

public ContactAdapter(Context context, ArrayList contactList) {
    super(context, R.layout.row_contact_list, contactList);

    this._context = context;
    this._contactList = contactList;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // Create inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if(convertView == null) {
        // Get rowView from inflater
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_contact_list, parent, false);

        this.holder = new ViewHolder();

        // Get childViews within rowView
        holder.urlView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_url);
        holder.contactLoading = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_loading);
        holder.nameView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.urlView.setImageBitmap(null);
    }

    // Assign the values to the childViews
    // Either using library Picasso or own AsyncTask, in this case named ImageHelper
    //Picasso.with(this._context).load(_contactList.get(position).getUrl()).into(urlView);
    task = new ImageHelper(holder.urlView, holder.contactLoading);
    holder.urlView.setImageBitmap(null);
    task.execute(_contactList.get(position).getUrl());
    holder.nameView.setText(_contactList.get(position).getName());

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView urlView;
    TextView nameView;
    ProgressBar contactLoading ;
}
}
```

**Async Task**

```
public class ImageHelper extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private Boolean running = true;

public ImageHelper(ImageView imageView, ProgressBar progressBar) {
    this.imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    this.progressBar = progressBar;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    imageViewReference.get().setVisibility(View.GONE);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
    while (running) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection httpCon =
                    (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            if (httpCon.getResponseCode() != 200)
                throw new Exception("Failed to connect");
            InputStream is = httpCon.getInputStream();
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Image", "Failed to load image", e);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onCancelled() {
    running = false;
}

// Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
        final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
        if (imageView != null) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            imageViewReference.get().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
}
```

I appreciate any help I can get :)